# Find n-th smallest element in array without sorting?

Tags: c

I want to write a program to find the n-th smallest element without using any sorting technique..

Can we do it recursively, divide and conquer style like quick-sort?

If not, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find information about that problem here: [Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Answer (score 9):

What you are referring to is the Selection Algorithm, as previously noted. Specifically, your reference to quicksort suggests you are thinking of the [partition based selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm).

Here's how it works:

- Like in Quicksort, you start by picking a good
  pivot: something that you think is nearly
  half-way through your list. Then you
  go through your entire list of items
  swapping things back and forth until
  all the items less than your pivot
  are in the beginning of the list, and
  all things greater than your pivot
  are at the end. Your pivot goes into the leftover spot in the middle.
- Normally in a quicksort you'd recurse
  on both sides of the pivot, but for
  the Selection Algorithm you'll only
  recurse on the side that contains the
  index you are interested in. So, if
  you want to find the 3rd lowest
  value, recurse on whichever side
  contains index 2 (because index 0 is
  the 1st lowest value).
- You can stop recursing when you've
  narrowed the region to just the one
  index. At the end, you'll have one
  unsorted list of the "m-1" smallest
  objects, and another unsorted list of the "n-m" largest
  objects. The "m"th object will be inbetween.

This algorithm is also good for finding a sorted list of the highest m elements... just select the m'th largest element, and sort the list above it. Or, for an algorithm that is a little bit faster, do the Quicksort algorithm, but decline to recurse into regions not overlapping the region for which you want to find the sorted values.

The really neat thing about this is that it normally runs in O(n) time. The first time through, it sees the entire list. On the first recursion, it sees about half, then one quarter, etc. So, it looks at about 2n elements, therefore it runs in O(n) time. Unfortunately, as in quicksort, if you consistently pick a bad pivot, you'll be running in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

Answer (score 1):

This task is quite possible to complete within roughly `O(n)` time (`n` being the length of the list) by using a [heap structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_structure) (specifically, a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) based on a [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap)), which gives `O(1)` insertion time and `O(log n)` removal time).

Consider the task of retrieving the m-th smallest element from the list. By simply looping over the list and adding each item to the priority queue (of size `m`), you can effectively create a queue of each of the items in the list in `O(n)` time (or possibly fewer using some optimisations, though I'm not sure this is exceedingly helpful). Then, it is a straightforward matter of removing the element with lowest priority in the queue (highest priority being the smallest item), which only takes `O(log m)` time in total, and you're finished.

So overall, the time complexity of the algorithm would be `O(n + log n)`, but since `log n << n` (i.e. `n` grows a lot faster than `log n`), this reduces to simply `O(n)`. I don't think you'll be able to get anything significantly more efficient than this in the general case.

Comment: (1) how do you get a priority queue "of size m"? does it somehow know which is the largest item to throw away when you add another one? (2) assuming you had such a structure, i still don't see how you got O(log m). shouldn't you need to multiply by m because you need to remove m things to get to the m'th smallest item?

Comment: @newacct: You're essentially right about point 1. You can limit the size of the priority queue to some degree (by checking the max item after it fills, for example), but not to size m. Regarding point 2, that is not true. You can in fact retrieve the largest item in log n time (rather than m, with the correction of point 1) - the priority queue allows access to either the max or min items in log n time; it's only the ones inbetween that take longer to fetch.

Comment: Why is my solution above not best?..I want to find out whats the issue with my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use Binary heap, if u dont want to use fibonacci heap.

Algo:

1. Contruct the min binary heap from the array this operation will take O(n) time.
2. Since this is a min binary heap, the element at the root is the minimum value.
3. So keep on removing element frm root, till u get ur kth minimum value. o(1) operation
4. Make sure after every remove you re-store the heap kO(logn) operation.

So running time here is O(klogn) + O(n)............so it is O(klogn)...

Answer (score 0):

Two stacks can be used like this to locate the Nth smallest number in one pass.

- Start with empty Stack-A and Stack-B
- PUSH the first number into Stack-A
- The next number onwards, choose to PUSH into Stack-A only if the number is smaller than its top
- When you have to PUSH into Stack-A, run through these steps

  - While TOP of Stack-A is larger than new number, POP TOP of Stack-A and push it into Stack-B
  - When Stack-A goes empty or its TOP is smaller than new number, PUSH in the new number and restore the contents of Stack-B over it
  - At this point you have inserted the new number to its correct (sorted) place in Stack-A and Stack-B is empty again
  - If Stack-A depth is now sufficient you have reached the end of your search

---

I generally agree to Noldorins' optimization analysis.
This stack solution is towards a simple scheme that will work (with relatively more data movement -- across the two stacks). The heap scheme reduces the fetch for Nth smallest number to a tree traversal (`log m`).

If your target is an optimal solution (say for a large set of numbers or maybe for a programming assignment, where optimization and the demonstration of it are critical) you should use the heap technique.

The stack solution can be compressed in space requirements by implementing the two stacks within the same space of K elements (where K is the size of your data set). So, the downside is just extra stack movement as you insert.

Comment: Sounds like this algorithm is in general O(nm) time, n being the list length, m as in the m-th smallest element.

Comment: This is just an insertion sort.

Comment: Yes, this is just sorting using stack

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the Ans to find Kth smallest element from an array:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Nthmin=0,j=0,i;
int GetNthSmall(int numbers[],int NoOfElements,int Nthsmall);
int main()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Enter Size of array\n";
    cin>>size;
    int *arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    cout<<"\nEnter array elements\n";
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        cin>>*(arr+i);
    cout<<"\n";
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<*(arr+i)<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int result=GetNthSmall(arr,size,3);
    printf("Result = %d",result);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int GetNthSmall(int numbers[],int NoOfElements,int Nthsmall)
{
    int min=numbers[0];
    while(j<Nthsmall)
    {
        Nthmin=numbers[0];
        for(i=1;i<NoOfElements;i++)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                if(numbers[i]<min)
                {
                    min=numbers[i];
                }
                Nthmin=min;
            }
            else
            {
                if(numbers[i]<Nthmin && numbers[i]>min)
                    Nthmin=numbers[i];
            }
        }
        min=Nthmin;
        j++;
    }
    return Nthmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find the nth largest element in an array without using any sorting methods.

```
public static void kthLargestElement() {
    int[] a = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8 };
    int n = 3;
    int max = a[0], min = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
        }
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
        }

    }

    int max1 = max, c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] > min && a[j] < max) {
                max = a[j];
            }
        }
        min = max;
        max = max1;
        c++;
        if (c == (a.length - n)) {
            System.out.println(min);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work if array have repeated elements, eg: "int[] a = { 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 9, 8 };"